# Devemos editar perguntas com erros (graves) de ortografia?

Tags: debate, edição

Exemplos:

"Trabalho **a** 5 anos com Java e..."

"**Fazem** três semanas que eu tento resolver..."

"**Haviam** outras maneiras de elaborar..."

"**À partir** de hoje, vou tentar evitar..."

"Não sei **aonde** definir a variável..."

"**Ao** meu ver, devemos nos preocupar..."

"Eu **quiz** criar o plugin, **mais** algo..."

"PHP é a **linguajem** de **programassãum** **q** eu **axo** **q** **eh**..."

Comment: Acho que exagerei no último exemplo.

Comment: Não, só escreveu como um PHPeiro escreveria. (Pedras voando na minha direção em 3, 2, 1...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bom, quase todas citações são problemas gramaticais e não tão graves assim. Muitos até vão dizer que algumas dessas citações são erros seus :)

Mas enfim, problemas ortográficos, gramaticais, de digitação, e textos irrelevantes para o problema devem ser retirados para melhorar o entendimento e demonstrar que precisamos ter um padrão mínimo de qualidade. As postagens devem ser agradáveis de ler, não causar ojeriza.

Mas não podemos sair editando tudo. Quando a alteração é muito pequena, vai resolver um problema mínimo, quase invisível, deixa pra lá. Principalmente em casos que a postagem está bem compreensível.

Mas é comum ter vários problemas. Dói nos olhos ver tantos erros juntos.

Como o Sergio bem disse, tem que tomar cuidado para não exagerar. Não se preocupe com as diferenças culturais entre os países. Precisamos respeitar o padrão de cada um. O que é inaceitável é o erro, principalmente aqueles que foram causados por preguiça. Já perceberam como as pessoas odeiam usar o <kbd>shift</kbd>?

Eu mesmo uso o critério da relevância e extensão da edição. Algumas vezes um errinho eu deixo pra lá, mas quando vejo vários, eu conserto.

Costumo aprovar tudo que melhora razoavelmente. Mas é ruim quando alguém ganha +2 só porque trocou duas letrinhas. E o pior é que grande parte das edições que tenho que aprovar, eu tenho que melhorar, a pessoa realmente altera duas letras e tinha 20 para alterar.

Melhore o que está ruim, mas não seja tão perfeccionista de arrumar cada vírgula.

Cuidado com *à* e *há*. Em Portugal se usa diferente. Eu aprendi isso aqui e tenho que aprender muitas outras coisas.

Comment: "Cuidado com à e há. Em Portugal se usa diferente." – Não, o Zuul é que não sabe a regra :)

Comment: Não sei se foi só para não perder a piada, mas ele não é o único :)

Comment: Eu acho que sei por que, expliquei no chat outro dia... O jeito deles pronunciarem pode induzir ao erro na hora de escrever.

Comment: Pronuncia-se exactamente da mesma forma mas sim, aplica-se em diferentes contextos. Ja' agora, qual e' o nivel de dor a ler texto sem acentos? (como este, dado que nao uso teclado em portugues)

Comment: A edição deve sempre ter como propósito melhorar o post, deixá-lo mais claro e/ou mais preciso. Isso vale pra pra erros ortográficos, semânticos ou até técnicos. Mas como o @bigown disse, não há necessidade alguma de fazer edições mínimas só pra adequar um post à gramática formal... Se ele pode ser compreendido facilmente, deixe como está.

Comment: E quanto a saudações e agradecimentos? Será a ferro e a fogo como Stack Overflow americano? É uma prática comum novatos iniciarem um stack com Bom Dia/Boa tarde/Boa noite e encerrar com uma forma de agradecimento antecipado, até mesmo por timidez. No SO isso é vetado e sempre removido e já vi uma ou outra revisão desse tipo por aqui.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto saudações e agradecimentos têm mesmo sido removidos por aqui, e eu sou um dos reponsáveis. Você poderia postar uma discussão sobre isso aqui no meta, é um debate interessante.

Comment: @bigown Já que estamos numa de erros tenho uma dúvida. No seu segundo comentário você escreve: "Eu acho que sei por que,", queria saber se no Brasil é assim que se escreve porque em Portugal é: "Eu acho que sei porquê, é porque...."

Answer (score 7):

Todas as correções que melhorem a pergunta são bemvindas.

Quem faz a análise da sugestão pode optar por rejeitar a edição como sendo "demasiado pequena", mas com uma explicação clara de quem faz a sugestão (no campo próprio para resumo), será provavelmente aceite.

O site é de todos nós e ninguém escreve mal de propósito.

Deixo só uma nota para casos que possam ser nuances/diferenças entre Português do Brazil, de Portugal, ou outro país de lingua portuguêsa. Nesses casos é melhor deixar estar e respeitar a riqueza e variedade da nossa língua.

Comment: Português do _Brasil_ ;-)

Answer (score 5):

<sup>As respostas já existentes clarificam quando devemos ou não proceder a edições, vou apenas deixar o método que utilizo para discernir se vale à pena proceder à edição de algo.</sup>

As edições devem ser substanciais, promovendo o melhoramento da pergunta, resposta ou wiki de tag na sua globalidade.

Quando verifico que algo está incorrecto, costumo elaborar uma lista de coisas que podem ser melhoradas, e editar após análise da lista:

**Por exemplo, vou editar quando:**

- Lista com muitos tópicos a melhorar;
- Lista com poucos tópicos mas os mesmos são de teor técnico;
- Re-tag para melhor identificar o conteúdo;
- No caso particular de perguntas, se pouco podemos melhorar mas a mesma já existe à algum tempo e ainda não tem resposta ou das respostas existentes nenhuma está aceite. <sup>1</sup>

**Não vou editar quando:**

- Lista com um ou dois tópicos de pouca relevância (erro ortográfico em detalhe não técnico);
- Lista apenas contém o erro que foi visto e originou a criação da mesma;

---

## Exemplo Prático

Vamos ver o exemplo da seguinte pergunta:

[Detectada uma exceção não tratada. Código gerado: [68MJGTMV] e [XJEL5QC6] - Exception esperada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3230/223)

[image: Captura de Tela]

<sup>Captura de tela adicionada para garantir a veracidade do exemplo no futuro.</sup>

Se formos criar uma lista de alterações, entre outras vamos ter:

- Título pouco claro;
- Conteúdo sem bloco de comentário para o texto do erro;
- Conteúdo com erro na palavra "ingnorar";
- Conteúdo com erro na palavra "funicona";
- Conteúdo com erro na palavra "pa´gina";
- Palavra "exception" deveria estar com formatação de código;
- Referência ao ficheiro "salaBeans.xhtml" deveria estar com formatação de código;

Claramente esta pergunta merece ser editada pois pode ser aprimorada.

Se a lista ficasse pelas três palavras com erro ortográfico, neste caso em particular iria editar para causar um *bump* <sup>1</sup> na pergunta visto que a mesma se encontra até ao momento sem resposta aceite indicando que o problema poderá ainda estar por resolver.

## Conclusão

Em suma, ter sempre um pouco de atenção antes de iniciarmos uma edição de for a avaliar a relevância da mesma.

Observar também o panorama geral do tópico para apurar se o mesmo vai beneficiar da edição e do *bump* <sup>1</sup> que vai ser gerado.

---

<sup>1</sup> Bump é o termo comummente utilizado pelos utilizadores da SE para definir o acto de promover uma acção em determinado tópico que leve o mesmo para a página principal. As acções mais simples são a edição ou nova resposta.

Comment: Por isso que acho que precisa editar logo. Bem no nascimento não dá para dizer que há um bump de fato. Está ativo. Editar posteriormente já complica mais por causa do bump.