# Saudações e Agradecimentos

Tags: debate, edição

Conforme [sugerido](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/767/devemos-editar-perguntas-com-erros-graves-de-ortografia/777?noredirect=1#comment1718_777) como será a posição do Stack Overflow Português referente as saudações e agradecimentos?

Muitas vezes, talvez até mesmo por timidez por ser um recém-chegado de uma comunidade, os usuários tem o costume até mesmo inocente de iniciar seus *stacks* com uma saudação (Bom Dia / Boa Tarde / Boa Noite) e encerrá-los com um encerramento impessoal (Atenciosamente, por exemplo) ou de agradecimento antecipado.

Não somos o Stack Overflow, mas seguiremos o mesmo modelo cuja postura é remover essas ocorrências? Na versão americana até que é justificável, haja vista que um "Bom Dia" para o autor pode ser "Boa Noite" para o leitor do outro lado do mundo, mas aqui, que acredito ser uma comunidade com público formado muito mais de Brasileiros e Portugueses do que outros, a diferença de horário seria pequena, coisa de poucas horas.

E quanto ao agradecimento antecipado e explícito, apesar de não ter uma opinião muito sólida a esse respeito, não vejo como errado e, apesar de não transparecer a impessoalidade que um *stack* normalmente tem, é uma evolução natural do usuário que, eventual e possivelmente, deixará de fazê-lo.

Comment: Relacionada, talvez duplicata: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38/como-se-portar-ao-perguntar-responder

Comment: `Não somos o Stack Overflow`. Não, somos o [se]. E a regra da rede é ***ruído zero***. Se alguém quiser socializar aqui deve usar a função do [chat]. E quanto aos agradecimentos, é legal aproveitar e indicar *"agradeça votando positivamente as respostas úteis"*.

Comment: Alguém aqui tem filhos? Existe mil e uma maneiras de educar uma criança: no medo, no susto, no diálogo, com brutalidade, com gentileza. Esse "filho" que chega aqui sem saber que a "regra da rede" é "ruído zero", sem dúvida, precisa ser educado. Eu me questiono se **editar removendo** é mesmo a melhor forma de realizar essa *educação*. Como estamos vendo, tem pessoas que chegam a ver nisso o comportamento de um "[regime totalitarista](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1296/4707)". Mesmo que seja uma visão incorreta, pergunto: Tem alguma importância sermos vistos dessa maneira? Ou não?

Comment: É justamente nesse ponto o qual eu queria, de certa forma, chegar. Temos N fóruns de discussão Internet a fora os quais deixam o usuário fazer o que bem entendem. O modelo do SO garante que os stacks sejam geridos com punhos de ferro e, apesar de ser a favor de boa estruturação de conteúdo, ortografia e gramática, sou extremamente contra autoritarismo de Moderadores (calma, ninguém daqui ^_^) e imperativismo de dezenas de regras, cada vez mais absurdas (não que aqui hajam muitas).

Comment: @J.Bruni tem pessoas que enxergam totalitarismo em todo lugar. Todo mundo acha democracia boa quando é beneficiado por ela. Quando a democracia prejudica, devida ou indevidamente, aquela pessoa sempre acha que a democracia é ruim. A melhor forma de educar filhos é dar o exemplo, não é punindo. Edição é dar o exemplo. Negativar quem não se esforçou em entender qual é o comportamento esperado "na casa" é punição e sou contra punições. Não existe nada melhor que editar para a pessoa ver o que é esperado dela.

Comment: Há quem ache que deva colocar um comentário. Tem gente que "espana" justamente por causa do comentário avisando ela qual é o comportamento esperado. Há quem fique raivoso quando alguém edita e não fala nada. Ou seja nós vamos desagradar alguém sempre. O ideal seria que as pessoas fossem mais compreensivas, que tentassem entender que aquilo é para o benefício dela. Como isso não acontece vamos ter que conviver com essas situações. O que não podemos é mudar a filosofia do site. Eu só não entendo porque as pessoas querem transformar este site em mais um fórum. Gosta de fórum? Procure um!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Eu sou a favor de remover saudações e agradecimentos, coisa que tenho feito diariamente. Mesmo assim, entendo que isso possa parecer desagradável para o autor da pergunta ou resposta, especialmente na cultura brasileira (não sei ao certo quanto a outras culturas lusófonas).

Saudações e agradecimentos cumprem dois papéis na comunicação:

1. Abrir, testar e encerrar o canal de comunicação
2. Estabelecer empatia com o interlocutor

Na maioria das vezes, esses papéis se misturam, mas vou tratar de cada um separadamente

#### Abrir, testar e encerrar o canal de comunicação

Quando dizemos "alô" ao telefone (em Portugal, *'stou*), esperamos um resposta de volta, para ter certeza de que o outro está ouvindo. Da mesma forma, quando terminamos um diálogo com um "até mais" ou algo semelhante, isso serve para marcar que a comunicação termina ali.

Como aqui a comunicação é assíncrona (o momento da postagem não corresponde necessariamente ao momento da leitura), ambos são desnecessários. No caso de "bom dia" e afins, o fato de estarmos todos no mesmo fuso horário ou em fuso horários próximos é irrelevante. A pergunta ou resposta não será lida somente no momento em que foi postada. Um dos grandes objetivos do site é produzir conteúdo que fique disponível para qualquer pessoa, a qualquer momento.

#### Estabelecer empatia com o interlocutor

A gentileza é muito bem-vista na nossa cultura, e em muitas outras. Parte do papel das saudações, além de abrir/fechar o canal de comunicação, é estabelecer empatia com o outro. Um "bom dia" em parte quer dizer "estou te vendo/escutando, *e aberto a escutar o que você tem a me dizer*". É uma expressão de humildade, presente também no "por favor", no "obrigado", etc. E é nesse ponto que a remoção das saudações e agradecimentos pode incomodar. A pessoa pode pensar, "eu estava tentando ser educado, e alguém vai lá e arranca isso?" Aliás, qualquer tipo de edição pode causar esse sentimento em novos usuários.

Embora isso possa causar estranhamento, este é um site colaborativo, e [edições são bem-vindas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing). Aos poucos o usuário novo vai se acostumando com isso. Sei que a lingua inglesa e as culturas britânica e norte-americana são mais objetivas por natureza, e que talvez por isso essas edições sejam mais fáceis de aceitar no SO em inglês. Sei que para um latino-americano um texto muito objetivo pode parecer duro demais. Mas não é necessariamente o caso. Outras marcas de empatia ao longo do texto são suficientes para dar o tom desejado – e o tom de um texto nunca deve ser alterado numa edição, exceto se for ofensivo.

A remoção de algo que pretende comunicar um sentimento é delicada, mas a razão por trás dela é, do meu ponto de vista, nobre: deixar o texto mais objetivo. Textos mais objetivos focam na mensagem, e não nos interlocutores nem no canal de comunicação. A objetividade que vemos no Stack Overflow em inglês é para mim uma de suas grandes qualidades. Agradecimentos, saudações e assinaturas representam linhas extras na postagem (frequentemente entre duas e quatro, incluindo as em branco). Imagine se toda pergunta e resposta usasse um formato padronizado, iniciando com saudação e terminando com agradecimento. Não seria dispensável? O que interessa é o recheio, o conteúdo.

---

Dito isto, pretendo continuar fazendo esse tipo de edição em perguntas e respostas. A partir de agora, passarei a incluir um link para essa discussão no resumo da edição. Se houver um consenso aqui de que *não* devemos fazer mais esse tipo de edição, eu paro.

Comment: Realmente, olhando por esse ângulo faz todo sentido. Fico feliz que esse debate tenha atingido o propósito dele e gostaria de lhe parabenizar pela resposta. Quase rolou uma lágrimazinha masculina aqui. :p

Comment: Obrigado @BrunoAugusto :) Acho sempre bom debater esses assuntos, e estou aberto a opiniões contrárias, se surgirem.

Comment: Concordo. Essa questão dos agradecimentos e cumprimentos é o tipo de coisa em que a moderação pela comunidade funciona muito bem.

Comment: @bfavaretto: minha opinião não é exatamente "contrária"... veja meus comentários na resposta do PauloHDSousa... mas eu jamais iria editar uma resposta apenas para remover saudações, e o que aprendi no SO em inglês é que não se deve fazer edições minúsculas, tipo para meramente corrigir um "typo" (erro de digitação) - elas precisam ser "substanciais"... porém, sentir incômodo ou não por essas "decorações" é algo muito pessoal... pensando bem, eu acho que até **gosto** do tom que essas saudações dão... é subjetivo. Mas respeito essa busca pela "objetividade".

Comment: Continuei pensando no assunto... em suma, eu acho que deveria ser **ponderado** se o usuário novo / recém-chegado poderia sentir como uma "agressão" essa *edição em prol da objetividade* que acaba *removendo o seu esforço em ser simpático*. Será que vale a pena "ferir os sentimentos" desse usuário em prol de uma "militância pela objetividade do site"? Eu mesmo não sei a resposta, mas deixo o questionamento para reflexão.

Comment: @J.Bruni Também não sei a resposta, mas é bem raro ver alguém se queixar dessas edições (mas é verdade que podem estar feridos e quietos). Vou pensar sobre o assunto, embora obviamente eu seja a favor da remoção das saudações e agradecimentos.

Comment: É uma questão de peso: para você a boniteza e robustez do site é o que motiva sua ação. Isso é admirável. Fica a chamada à reflexão se a limpeza do site vale mais a pena do que possíveis cicatrizes em alguns visitantes...

Comment: ...eu pessoalmente acho melhor deixar quieto o emocional do visitante, mesmo em detrimento de uma limpeza maior no conteúdo do site.

Comment: Desculpe, mas discordo.. Por acaso você é assim no seu trabalho? E em casa? A EDUCAÇÃO é fundamental onde quer que esteja, além do mais os colegas aqui não tem obrigação de ajudar, pois sem uma saudação, acaba tendo essa conotação.

Comment: @Jose.Marcos Você não precisa se desculpar por discordar de mim ;)

Comment: @Jose.Marcos Historicamente os sites no Stack Exchange tentam prezar pela clareza e objetividade das perguntas e resposta. A decisão de remover saudações e agradecimentos busca remover do post tudo que não for essencial ao conteúdo, pra que as milhares de pessoas que o encontrarem no futuro não tenham que ler algo que é, essencialmente, irrelevante pra qualidade da resposta. Por outro lado, o que você falou faz muito sentido, e deve ser levado em consideração. A decisão nesse post não é definitiva, e pode ser mudada no futuro, caso haja uma nova discussão e as pessoas apoiem uma mudança.

Comment: Particularmente dar um "Boa noite colegas", "Olá a todos".... ou .... "Obrigado pela ajuda", "Muito grato pela força", "Obrigado"...acho válido... diferente de "Tenho o código que faz isso e aquilo, porém está com problemas. Alguém pode me ajudar?"... depois de um colega aparecer, perder seu precioso tempo, quebrar a cabeça e ajudar...finalizar com... "OK... funcionou!!"... Dá a entender que foi uma obrigação e não uma ajuda...

Answer (score 12):

Conforme já exposto nas restantes respostas, não faz qualquer sentido numa pergunta existirem cumprimentos, saudações, assinaturas ou agradecimentos.

### Cumprimentos ou Saudações

São coisas que utilizamos em cartas, emails e cenários do género, não dizemos "Bom dia" sempre que colocamos uma pergunta a um professor na sala de aulas pois não?

### Assinaturas e Agradecimentos

As perguntas e as respostas já são assinadas pelo sistema através da aplicação da caixa que identifica o titular.

Não é necessário agradecer por escrito, É NECESSÁRIO agradecer através do uso da seta de votar-a-favor.

---

Não quero deixar de mencionar um detalhe importante, e que é essencialmente o meu contributo para este assunto:

À muito tempo atrás, eu coloquei uma pergunta no METÃO sobre o facto de dever aceitar ou rejeitar as edições sugeridas onde quem as realizou estava unicamente a proceder à remoção de assinaturas e/ou cumprimentos:

[Reject or approve suggested edits for “removed clutter”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139830/184576)

Apesar de eu os rejeitar todos, quis apurar se era um procedimento correto ou estava realmente a prejudicar os utilizadores que se davam ao trabalho de editar algo para remover este tipo de conteúdos.

A resposta dada pelo **Bill the Lizard♦** foi bastante esclarecedora:

Este tipo de comportamento não é aceite nem é saudável. As edições devem ser substanciais e não limitadas ao facto de se remover duas ou três palavras.

Por outro lado, uma edição deste género é perfeitamente válida se e apenas se, a única coisa a melhorar é efectivamente remover "muletas" do tipo: Cumprimentos, Saudações, Assinaturas e Agradecimentos.

Comment: +1 por **As edições devem ser substanciais e não limitadas ao fato de se remover duas ou três palavras.**

Comment: Não entendi seu último parágrafo: _"Por outro lado, uma edição deste género é perfeitamente válida se e apenas se, a única coisa a melhorar é efectivamente remover "muletas" do tipo: Cumprimentos, Saudações, Assinaturas e Agradecimentos."_ Me parece que você contradisse tudo que havia dito até então.

Comment: @Math Não propriamente. Apesar de parecer contraditório, se vamos editar algo onde a única coisa a melhorar é somente remover a "muleta", então, a edição é válida. Agora, se removemos "muletas" e deixamos outros melhoramentos para trás, melhoramentos esses importantes e realmente significativos, a edição é inválida e deve ser rejeitada.

Comment: @Zuul agora entendi seu ponto de vista, valeu pela explicação

Answer (score 10):

O SO tem um script que limpa os cumprimentos e agradecimentos dos posts, e até onde eu saiba a idéia foi implementada aqui também. Acho uma solução mais aplicável que dizer pra alguém que ele *não pode* falar "Oi".

A lista de frases que ele elimina não é completa, obviamente, e volta e meia um ou outro podem acabar passando pelo filtro. Nesse caso, se alguém se sentir particularmente disposto, sinta-se à vontade para editar e remover. Mas ressalto que não vejo porque deixar um comentário "instruindo" a pessoa a não fazer algo que, do ponto de vista do autor, é educação básica.

Por bastante tempo, todos os meus posts no SO tinham pelo menos um "obrigado", e todos eles foram removidos, sem que ninguém me dissesse pra parar. Eventualmente, como você falou, as pessoas normalmente deixam de fazê-lo.

Comment: Você tem mais informações sobre esse filtro automático? Por exemplo, que tipo de coisa ele consegue pegar, e o que deixa passar?

Comment: Ele pega cumprimentos clássicos (oi, olá, etc.) que apareçam no início dos posts, e os agradecimentos que apareçam no final (obrigado, valeu, etc.). Não é profundamente rebuscado, mas funciona.

Comment: @Gabe Pega "Olá" no início do post tipo este: [http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1296/223](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1296/223) ? ;)

Comment: @Zuul Obviamente, os nossos devs não são dos mais gabaritados :D

Comment: Esse script alguma vez já funcionou aqui no SOPT? Com uma [busca muito simples](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?page=36&tab=newest&q=ol%C3%A1) achei vários posts começando com "Olá". Alguns bem antigos, [por exemplo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6717/3117).

Comment: @Math essa pergunta já foi respondida?

Comment: @JorgeB. não foi não, mas eu diria que nunca funcionou mesmo.

Answer (score 9):

O debate é um pouco fragmentado nos comentários em vários posts. Vou tentar falar de alguns pontos levantados.

Tem países que não é educado apertar a mão da pessoa, você vai forçar essas pessoas apertarem sua mão? Isso é educação?

Aqui se convencionou que o educado é manter os posts limpos. A cultura aqui sempre foi desde 2008 no SO e desde 2013 no SOpt que isso seria adotado.

Tentar impor sua forma de fazer as coisas, por mais bem intencionado que seja, é falta de educação.

Educado é fazer o que uma comunidade está acostumada a fazer.

Falta de educação é cada um fazer do jeito que bem entende.

Ter consideração por uma comunidade é entender como ela funciona e seguir esse *modus operandi*.

Não se preocupar ou querer subverter esse *modus operandi* é mostrar desconsideração pela comunidade.

---

Como sempre surge acusações de totalitarismo nessas questões eu costumo tentar informar que as pessoas não entendem democracia. Democracia é o que a comunidade quer. O que algumas pessoas querem é que é totalitarismo. Totalitarismo só ocorre onde você não tem opção. Como pode haver totalitarismo em uma comunidade de internet? Não gosta do jeito que a comunidade opera? Vai procurar uma outra que lhe agrade mais. Querer que essa comunidade mude o seu jeito de operar para atender seu gosto específico é que é totalitarismo.

Não existe nenhuma comunidade na internet que lhe agrade? Crie uma do seu jeito e faça dela um sucesso. E quando ela for um sucesso, ceda a toda reclamação que alguém fizer de que não é assim que essa comunidade que você criou deve operar. Mostre que você é tão democrático que vai atender **todos** os desejos de **todos** que apareçam lá.

Note que dá para discutir aqui. Não reclamo disso. Isso é democrático. Mas forçar algo que a comunidade não deseja é o mais perto que podemos chamar de totalitarismo.

E note que não reclamo muito das pessoas que colocam saudações ou fazem coisas que não é desejável nesta comunidade. Acho falta de educação fazer algo em uma comunidade sem entender como ela funciona, mas eu consigo entender essa falta de educação.

Esses dias estava dando uma lida no histórico do chat aqui e vi uma discussão do Gabe sobre a questão a organização social do site. Ele falava que este site é mais uma meritocracia que uma democracia. Para o bem ou para o mal, é isso mesmo. Boa observação. Meritocracia tem seus defeitos mas é uma forma de organizar uma comunidade e é justamente ela que atrai usuários que contribuem positivamente mais que em outros sites.

Não me lembro bem mas ele ainda dizia que isso tem seus defeitos. Assim como a democracia. Acho que todos conhecem a frase "que a democracia é a pior forma de governo depois de todos os outros" (acho que é do Winston Churchill). E é verdade, democracia é terrível, especialmente quando ela vai contra o que você deseja. Mas quando você obtêm o que **você** deseja em detrimento de outros, só é "democrático" para você. E democracia não existe o **eu**, o **você**, existe o **todos**.

Mas é ingênuo achar que todos significa todos mesmo. Não existe unanimidade em nada. Democracia é o que a maioria deseja. E essa maioria nem precisa ser qualificada. É democrático deixar que apenas a parte mais interessada decida o que é bom para todos. Se uma pessoa não quer se meter no debate, não quer ajudar decidir, ok. A única coisa que ela não pode é fazer o que bem entende porque ela não participou do debate.

"Ah, mas o debate aconteceu quando eu não estava aqui". Você pode até reabrir o debate. Mas se não tiver uma argumento muito forte, se não trouxer um benefício muito claro algo consagrado em uma comunidade não vai mudar.

Eu adoraria voltar na década de 40 e debater a criação da previdência no Brasil e que ela tivesse sido em cima de poupança prévia e não começasse pagar benefícios para quem nunca contribuiu. Isso teria mudado a cada do Brasil. Mas é tarde demais. Agora todos pagamos o preço por isso.

Qual o benefício em deixar saudações? Agradar quem gosta das coisas mais desorganizadas? Agradar quem não gosta do formato de perguntas e respostas? Agradar quem sequer quer pensar sobre a validade de saudar alguém em uma pergunta ou resposta? Existe algum benefício real?

Democracia é fazer escolha. Democracia não é agradar todo mundo. Todo mundo vai dizer que sabe que democracia não vai agradar todo mundo. Mas parece que poucos entendem o que isso significa.

Eu não gosto de perguntas "help desk". Mas e daí? Eu vou impor isso? Eu vou conviver com elas, outras pessoas gostam. Elas não me causam tantos problemas assim e agradam outras pessoas, então eu as aceito.

---

Aceitar um estilo mais informal, mais social é uma faca de dois gumes. Um dos motivos que a rede Stack Exchange funciona muito bem é que ela atrai bons profissionais. E atrai justamente porque é mais direto, porque não é rede social, porque o bom profissional fica focado no problema.

Já houve época que os sites da rede forma um pouquinho mais liberais e isso puxava cada vez mais quem só queria socializar e afastava mais os bons profissionais.

O que adianta você ter fóruns que permitem as pessoas se expressarem como querem se as respostas que os usuários conseguem não são boas?

Mas todos que preferem essa forma de comunicação podem ir lá nesses fóruns e serem felizes.

O que muitos não entendem é que essa forma mais rígida e a qualidade das respostas estão interligadas.

Não dá para ter tudo.

---

O que fazer?

Alguém fez uma comparação com educar filhos. Sim precisamos educar os filhos. O maior problema da sociedade hoje é não educar os filhos. E quase todo mundo acha que está fazendo isso.

Como educar os filhos aqui?

Punição não costuma funcionar a não ser que o "filho" queira impor sua vontade a qualquer custo, que ele seja agressivo, que outras forma não funcionem. Ainda bem que aqui apesar de uma ou outra birra infantil, todos acabam entendendo de uma forma ou de outra que precisa respeitar as regras da comunidade.

Educar é dar o exemplo. É mostrar sutilmente como deve operar. É fazer uma edição que mostra para o usuário que é daquela forma que operamos aqui.

Há quem responda bem com isso há quem não goste.

Tem que prefira que um comentário seja deixado ensinando a pessoa como proceder. Tem quem não goste destes comentários.

Não há maneira de agradar a todos. Cada um vai ficar bravo por uma razão, não importa o que você faça. Se não fizer nada vai desagradar outro grupo.

Mas a intervenção nas postagens sempre foi uma ferramenta que ajudou a qualidade aqui e isso não vai ser deixado de lado.

Se alguém tem uma sugestão que melhore a qualidade do conteúdo e não perturbe as pessoas que gostam de fazer tudo do jeito que bem entendem, vamos ouvir. Mas desde 2008 pessoas tentaram e não conseguiram achar uma forma.

Se tiver que escolher um tipo de usuário, eu escolho o que goste de qualidade, de organização, o que faz este site ser um sucesso. E o sucesso dele não vem das perguntas feitas de qualquer jeito e sim das respostas acima da média.

Há uma relação direta entre a baixa qualidade dos posts e a necessidade de escrever o que não é necessário. Isso já foi medido pela equipe da SE.

É melhor que não aconteça mas se para melhorar a qualidade tiver que aborrecer quem gosta de desorganização, quem não se esforça para se integrar a comunidade, quem só quer sugar, não tenho nenhum problema com isso.

---

No caso específico de colocar "Bom dia" eu tiro todos os que eu vejo. Aí já é falta de educação, nos dois sentidos da palavra. E mostra que as pessoas usam e nem sabem pra que serve um "Bom dia". Eu odeio ler um "Bom dia" quando está escuro. Mostra que é automatismo. É dar bom dia pra cachorro. Não mostra interesse genuíno de desejar bom dia.

Saudação eu tiro só se o post tem outro problema, mas "Bom dia" não dá.

Tem gente que acha que eu edito tudo o que vejo pela frente, mas eu deixo passar muita coisa. Raramente conserto só um problema, e quando é apenas um, costuma ser grave.

---

Estou aproveitando o tópico que está popular, mas essa questão já foi aberta em [Como se portar ao perguntar/responder](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/38/como-se-portar-ao-perguntar-responder) e [Como dizer obrigado em respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/605/como-dizer-obrigado-em-respostas) e [Onde podemos socializar?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/587/onde-podemos-socializar).

A parte mais importante é que comentários são bem mais liberais. Lá até dá para socializar moderadamente. Perguntas e respostas devem ser perguntas e respostas!

Note que o sistema tem heurísticas para tirar certos textos automaticamente, até mesmo em comentário. Mas para a alegria dos socializadores parece que não funciona muito bem em português.

Comment: Em nome da comunidade, te autorizo a remover, além do "bom dia", qualquer "aê galera!" que encontrar pela frente. :)

Comment: Esqueci do "fala aí galera" :)

Comment: Falando sério agora: acho muito importante a referência que você faz ao passado, ao "desde 2008". Aqui não é o SOen, todos concordamos com isso. Mas o engine por trás dele é o mesmo. E não se trata apenas de um software, que pode ser usado como as pessoas bem entenderem (até para outra coisa que não perguntas e respostas). O software traz com ele os anos de experiência de uso com milhões de usuários, em diversos sites. Tem coisas que variam de site para site, mas tem constantes também. Acho que cabe à SE, por meio do Gabe, deixar mais claro quais são essas constantes, todos ganharão com isso.

Answer (score 5):

Acho que a maior indignação do povo que se sente ofendido é o sentimento de *invasão* quando vem alguém e mexe em alguma coisa sua, no nosso caso as publicações, seja essa *invasão*  para retirar uma saudação seja para formatar um link de uma maneira adequada ou qualquer outro tipo de alteração em uma publicação originalmente sua.

As pessoas que se sentem incomodadas quando isso acontece ainda não entenderam que aqui é uma comunidade *colaborativa*, logo, se alguém mexeu na sua publicação foi com intenção de melhorá-la. Para agravar a situação, alguns usuários não entendem que remover saudações é uma oportunidade de aprimoramento de sua publicação, pois principalmente os novos usuários não conhecem as regras da comunidade, logo se sentem ofendidos duas vezes.

Eu chamaria o processo de retirar as saudações das publicações dos novatos de **Processo de Educação**.

Assim como na vida, que somos educados de acordo com os costumes da sociedade e quando crescemos estranhamos costumes de outros povos, como por exemplo nós latinos, estranhamos os costumes dos árabes, dos asiáticos e até mesmo dos americanos.

Eu particularmente não conhecia nenhum site de perguntas e respostas no Brasil, fiquei sabendo recentemente do GUJ, mas meu ponto é que pelo menos nós brasileiros, estamos muito acostumados com os fóruns e quando chegamos em um site de perguntas e respostas estranhamos um pouco os costumes de uma comunidade diferente, e não há nada de errado nisso, só que existe um período de ambientação que os novos usuários devem passar para entenderem as regras da comunidade, e enquanto isso não acontece situações de conflito acabam sendo criadas por bobeiras.

Acho que comparar atitudes de quem edita publicações com as atitudes de um ditador, regime isso, regime aquilo, Hitler... seria a mesma coisa que comparar esses termos com a educação que nossos pais nos deram quando éramos crianças. Geralmente quando crescemos damos valor a todas as brigas que tivemos com nossos pais quando criança, pois na época não entendíamos por que eles faziam o que faziam, mas hoje tudo faz sentido, não faz?

Na minha opinião, não podemos deixar *a coisa correr solta*, temos regras, temos que segui-las e temos que educar novos membros da comunidade, senão vira bagunça.

#### Apenas para ilustrar o por quê ...

... de não termos espaço para saudações: Imagine que você tem um livro de referência da sua linguagem de programação preferida. Entretanto para cada assunto que o livro aborda tem um `Olá` e um `Atenciosamente`.

[image: Carinha do Gabe]

---

<sup>Desculpa a referência aí @J. Bruni, só quis deixar meu exemplo bem completo ;-)</sup>

<sup>Desculpa também ao Gabe que robei a carinha, rsrs</sup>

Comment: Excelente resposta. Só lembrando que o Q&A do GUJ é um completo fracasso e o o fórum é tem mais brigas que soluções :D

Answer (score 3):

Acho que toda forma de cumprimento é desnecessária. Isso adiciona volume aos textos sem adicionar conteúdo útil. Em outras palavras, é apenas **recheio de linguiça**.

Bom dia, boa tarde e boa noite são ainda mais inconvenientes. Ainda que o *SOpt* fosse feito apenas para os usuários do Brasil ou de Portugal, o fato de eu escrever uma pergunta em um determinado horário não significa que ela será lida por todos na mesma parte do dia. E ainda adicionam uma certa estranheza. Acho muito engraçado quando vejo uma pergunta antiga em algum site do *Stack Exchange* e vejo um "bom dia", embora esteja eu a ler no período da noite.

Acredito que certas cortesias (mas não cumprimentos) têm lugar aqui. Por exemplo, em um comentário onde pedimos por código, não vejo problema em pedir "por favor". Acho que "obrigado" tem lugar em um comentário, desde que não seja o comentário inteiro - senão se torna apenas ruído.

Answer (score 1):

Para mim, sinceramente, **tanto faz** remover saudações e agradecimentos ou não.

A mim, esse "ruído" que para alguns é "encheção de linguiça" para mim é mais uma "**melodia agradável**", totalmente inofensiva e absolutamente não prejudicial à objetividade.

Mas compreendo que essa **percepção** é subjetiva. Tem gente que gosta de Carnaval. Tem gente que detesta. Alguns preferem sertanejo, outros música erudita - e dentre estes os que preferem extravagâncias como o Concerto para Piano e Orquestra Número 5 de Prokofiev, e outros que preferem obras mais bem comportadas, como os Noturnos de Chopin.

Se foi proclamado e elevado como "regra" um "consenso" de que esse "ruído" é "prejudicial", tal consenso não ressoa com minha personalidade. Porém, subjugo-me, pois afinal pertenço a esta comunidade.

Voltando ao ponto inicial desta minha resposta: para mim, sinceramente, **tanto faz** remover saudações e agradecimentos ou não.

O que importa, sim, para mim, mais do que a regra ou o consenso ou a remoção ou não... é sim o **respeito à pessoa** que redigiu tal saudação ou agradecimento.

É por esse simples motivo que eu pessoalmente nunca irei fazer edições removendo tais expressões do conteúdo, independente de quaisquer argumentações intelectuais.

---

Existe um livro de filosofia, do qual infelizmente não me recordo o título nem o autor, pois interagi com o mesmo há cerca de 15 anos atrás, onde o autor analisa as justificativas intelectuais e racionais por trás do "holocausto" judeu: o extermínio de milhares de vidas humanas nos campos de concentração nazistas. Toda a obra girava em torno do fato "curioso" de que toda aquela **ciência** aplicada às **máquinas da morte**, como câmaras de gás, e outras tecnologias de tortura, tinham fundamentos **racionais**, justificativas, argumentos, teorias. Não se tratava do fruto de um impulso momentâneo. O extermínio tinha justificativas racionais, e bem elaboradas!

Na contramão do que alguns entendem ser um princípio que rege esta rede, eu realmente não tenho outros argumentos, justificativas ou teorias para citar ou referenciar. Apenas um sentimento de **respeito à pessoa** é que justifica essa minha atitude de me recusar a fazer edições removendo saudações e agradecimentos.

P.S. - Estou na expectativa de *downvotes* para esta resposta... Sem saber bem o motivo, envio-a assim mesmo... Me sinto como que fazendo a voz de quem não tem voz aqui... Perda de tempo?

Comment: Downvote não seria o caso porque você mesmo disse que não se importa. Então se tem uma pergunta que não merece down, nem por quem gosta nem por quem não gosta, é a sua. Também não vou lembrar onde vi (é bem conhecido) que qualquer assunto pode ser comparado a Hitler, nazismo, holocausto, ditadura, totalitarismo e coisas do gênero, até mesmo se trancar dentro de casa e não interagir com outras pessoas, porque sempre vai acabar contrariar alguém, até quando tudo o que você quer fazer é não contrariar qualquer pessoa.

Comment: Eu deixei a resposta sair e postei como saiu... acho que é para alguém refletir... entende? Aí está. Eu ia cortar essa parte aí do nazismo, inclusive postei sem ela, mas aí senti que devia deixar, e deixei. Penso que essa minha resposta não está boa, mas assim mesmo que ela *precisava* existir mesmo imperfeita para movimentar certos neurônios e hormônios em algum rincão por aí...

Comment: Concordo, o importante é a pergunta, se a pessoa vai escrever um bom dia ou não, não irá mudar em nada o conteúdo.

Comment: Entenda que não fazer saudação/agradecer é a cultura/convenção da comunidade. @PauloHDSousa, e se alguém iniciar com um 'bom dia' e a pessoa estiver lendo a noite? Mas a questão nem é essa, o ponto é tratar perguntas e respostas como documentos, sem pessoalidade.

Comment: Depois de expressar minha opinião, e refletir sobre os retornos, estou mais propenso a **compreender** que editar a resposta removendo saudações e agradecimentos **não significa** desrespeitar a pessoa (que é o ponto **importante** para mim).

Comment: A princípio pode **parecer rude**, mas mediante tudo o que foi exposto aqui, trata-se meramente de "deixar a casa limpa" e seguir um determinado padrão. Eu nunca deixaria alguém fumar dentro da minha casa (e olha que eu mesmo já fui fumante - felizmente durou pouco e já foi faz tempo).

Answer (score -9):

**Não vejo nada de prejudicial em um usuário adicionar uma saudação**

Não considero que começar uma pergunta com um simples **olá**, prejudique a comunidade de alguma forma, tão pouco terminar escrevendo **atenciosamente.**

Por acaso quando vocês chegam em um lugar, simplesmente passam direto ou dão no mínimo um **olá**?

Proibir a pessoa de escrever do modo que ela quer desde que não ofenda ninguém me parece mais uma atitude de regime **totalitarista**, o pior ainda é editar o conteúdo removendo a **saudação/comprimento**.

Caso tenham dúvidas sobre a qualidade das perguntas quando há uma saudação, segue um [fórum que tem o mesmo objetivo do Stack](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-br/home).

E quero relatar um caso de edição que aconteceu com um colega de trabalho.

A pergunta era :

> Como vocês faziam nos navegadores antigos para fazer uma requisição AJAX.

Meu amigo respondeu.

> *Eu usava isso a 6 anos atras*

E foi editado para

> *Eu uso isso*

Um exemplo de edição desnecessária ao meu ver, e vai continuar assim até quando?

Comment: Este site não tem o mesmo objetivo. Aqui é um site de perguntas e respostas, deve conter apenas perguntas e respostas. Saudações fazem parte de conversa, funciona muito bem onde conversas são valorizadas (fóruns e redes sociais por exemplo). Eu particularmente sou extremamente crítico com a qualidade da respostas do fórum apresentado. Apesar de ter alguma coisa boa, a maioria é bem confusa e a quantidade de erros chega ser absurda. Saudação cria apenas ruido no pergunta ou na resposta. Você tem o direito de discordar, mas precisa entender que ESTA comunidade funciona melhor assim.

Comment: É normal todo usuário que entra no SO fazer uma saudação, mas a proposta da comunidade é manter no corpo da questão apenas a pergunta em si. Ninguém vai ser punido por isso, mas pode ser editado por convenção. E como Gabe escreveu, existe um script que elimina as saudações automaticamente.

Comment: Vale também mencionar que a remoção desse tipo de coisa é das poucas "regras" que têm [respaldo oficial](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) aqui no site.

Comment: Prezado Paulo, concordo que **não há nada de prejudicial em um usuário adicionar uma saudação**, especialmente se for um usuário novo, recém-chegado, que ainda não conhece bem a comunidade. Também penso que não há nada de prejudicial em tomar conhecimento e na medida do possível seguir as regras da comunidade, caso haja interesse em pertencer e continuar interagindo com a mesma. Eu particularmente não sinto prejuízo no tom coloquial e amigável, mas compreendo, respeito e sigo as regras que existem na comunidade à qual estou me integrando.

Comment: Pessoalmente eu jamais irei editar um conteúdo removendo saudações. Sinceramente, não é algo que eu faria... Por outro lado, assim como não vejo nada de prejudicial num usuário adicionar a saudação, também não vejo nada de prejudicial num membro editar o conteúdo removendo a saudação: esse membro está fazendo isso sentindo que está fazendo um bem à comunidade, e realmente sente o ambiente **melhor** sem a saudação: o que há de prejudicial nisso? A comunidade adotou esse padrão... eu nunca irei editar nada para remover uma saudação, mas não vejo nada de prejudicial em outro membro fazê-lo.

Comment: A edição para remoção de cumprimentos foi algo que aconteceu comigo quando comecei a usar o SO. Me sentia constrangido quando acontecia, como se estivesse levando uma repreensão, mas com o tempo eu assimilei a mensagem sem precisar que me chamassem a atenção explicitamente. Por isso gosto da ideia de que as edições "ensinam através de exemplo". Não tiro a validade do seu argumento, de que elas podem ser autoritárias, e talvez haja uma forma melhor de se guiar os usuários mas o intuito por trás de uma edição nunca é de *repreender*.

Comment: Paulo, essa edição que você citou agora parece mesmo incorreta. Edições nunca devem alterar o sentido pretendido pelo autor. Você tem um link para a resposta?

Comment: Tenho sim, segue http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3167/requisicao-ajax-com-javascript-puro-sem-apis, meu colega é o Venatci

Comment: @PauloHDSousa desculpa se ofendi alguém com minha edição, o que se passou pela minha cabeça naquele momento foi que aquilo não era uma resposta (correta) do jeito que estava. Por que? Por que se há 6 anos ele **fazia** daquele jeito, significa que hoje em dia ele faz diferente, logo, se ele mudou o jeito de fazer o que aconteceu nesse meio tempo? Ele descobriu um jeito melhor de se fazer? Ele achou um bug no jeito que ele fazia e consertou? Na minha opinião ele adicionou aquela palavras por um receio de afirmar a resposta, do tipo: "Faça assim", "Faça assado" (continua)

Comment: Portanto eu editei a resposta não por autoritarismo nem nada, eu alterei pq eu achei que ele precisava de um empurrãozinho de confiança nas palavras que ele usou. Na minha opinião as respostas não devem tentar debater a pergunta ou deixar margens para dúvidas, elas devem simplesmente responder. [**Link aqui**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/14941/revisions)

Comment: Só lembrando que uma edição errada e retirada da saudação são assuntos completamente diferentes. Na verdade todo o edit nada tem a ver com o assunto tratado aqui e deveria ser uma outra pergunta ou ser tratada onde o assunto faz sentido. Colocar mais que um assunto no mesmo lugar só dificulta o entendimento de todos.

Comment: @bigown concordo. O autor da resposta pode criar um novo tópico para discutir o assunto em questão se achar necessário, mas como o assunto foi posto em mesa eu resolvi dar meu parecer já que eu era uma parte envolvida na discussão. Agora que já dei meu parecer informo que não responderei mais aqui sobre esse assunto, mas estou disposto a conversar sobre ele seja no bate papo ou em um tópico exclusivo para ele.

Comment: Obviamente, não pude resistir ;) . . . . O exemplo do "causo do amigo" não tem a ver com o tema em pauta. Na verdade, é uma edição equivocada mesmo.

Comment: Eis um déspota esclarecido :) @brasofilo