# Como proceder em relação a divulgação de outros sites?

Tags: debate, autopromoção

Hoje me deparei com a seguinte [**RESPOSTA**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/39630/3) a essa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37796/erro-no-hor%C3%A1rio-de-ver%C3%A3o-summer-time-no-bootstrap-datepicker/39630#39630)

> Tive esse problema recentemente. Para corrigí-lo editei um trecho o
>   método fill do bootstrap-datepicker que antes era assim:
>
> ```
> var prevMonth = new Date(year, month - 1, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0),
>    day = DPGlobal.getDaysInMonth(prevMonth.getFullYear(), prevMonth.getMonth());
> ```
>
> E depois ficou assim:
>
> ```
> var prevMonth = new Date(year, month - 1, 28, 12, 0, 0, 0),
>    day = DPGlobal.getDaysInMonth(prevMonth.getFullYear(), prevMonth.getMonth());
> ```
>
> E o método parseDate, onde era:
>
> ```
> date.setHours(0);
> ```
>
> Ficou:
>
> ```
> date.setHours(12);
> ```
>
> Gostaria ainda de aconselhá-lo a acompanhar o nosso
>   http://chegadegambiarra.com, site onde postamos várias matérias
>   interessantes sobre melhoria de código, comportamento profissional,
>   processos dentre outros #ficadica

Gostaria de saber como eu devo proceder em relação a divulgação a outros sites!

Comment: O link é totalmente não relacionado a resposta em si. Se fosse um site dele, mas fosse o link de uma postagem sobre o tema que desse esclarecimentos mais amplos relevantes, não veria problema. Mas como está agora, é meramente spam.

Comment: Deixei um comentário lá e editei a resposta. O link realmente não cabia lá.

Comment: Relacionado: [Remover “Copyright” de resposta com código que não é uma biblioteca de verdade?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4203/3635)

Answer (score 11):

Aquela nota de rodapé da resposta cabe muito bem no "Sobre mim" do usuário que postou a resposta, que diga-se de passagem está vazio.

O site costuma evitar qualquer tipo de interferência nas publicações, seja na pergunta ou nas respostas. Aqui costumamos evitar saudações, agradecimentos e propagandas, uma discussão relativamente extensa sobre esse assunto pode ser encontrado aqui: [Saudações e Agradecimentos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/846/3117)

Se o link fosse vital para o entendimento da resposta faria sentido em mantê-lo, mas do jeito que está é meramente promocional e foge do escopo do site.

A ação correta pode ser: editar / sinalizar para um moderador / trazer o assunto para o Meta.

Para a resposta em questão eu editei ela removendo o link e deixei um recado para o autor da resposta.

Comment: eu não sabia como proceder, editei mas não exclui a ultima parte, e trouxe para o meta

Comment: @Joannis sem problemas! Na dúvida sempre o Meta é a solução mais adequada.

Comment: Relevante na Central de Ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior