# Como remover uma resposta bem-intencionada sem ser um babaca?

Tags: debate, comportamento, exclusão

Tenho visto vários casos em que o autor da pergunta posta uma resposta mostrando como a solução de outro usuário foi aplicada no seu código. Um caso bem claro é [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55787), em que o AP postou exatamente o código da pergunta com as alterações sugeridas na resposta aceita. O único conteúdo adicional é um agradecimento.

Respostas como essa na essência são só isso mesmo: um gesto de agradecimento do autor pela ajuda recebida. Nesse sentido [podem ser consideradas ruído](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/851), e se forem removidas não causarão nenhuma perda de informação; pelo contrário, a remoção aumenta a razão de sinal sobre ruído do site.

Mas convenhamos que responder a uma gentileza com uma tesourada seca (um voto para remover) não é muito simpático, e pode assustar usuários que não conhecem bem o estilo do site. Comentários enlatados das filas de análise também não ajudam muito, podem até confundir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como moderador, muitas vezes chego nessas respostas por meio de uma sinalização (foi o caso desta). Mas nem sempre é claro o que fazer. Uma conversão para comentário requer eliminar a maior parte da resposta (geralmente o código todo ou quase). Excluir é a tesourada seca que eu falei, a resposta some silenciosamente. Alguém sugere uma forma mais humana de lidar com as pessoas nesses casos? Algum comentário que possamos usar e reusar nesses casos?

---

**UPDATE**

Passados quase dois dias, resolvi excluir a resposta. Converter em comentário já não faria mais sentido, pois já havia um comentário de agradecimento na resposta aceita. Após excluir deixei o seguinte comentário (que vai gerar notificação):

> Olá @Dmgp. Acabei excluindo sua resposta pois ela não acrescentava informações novas, mas agradeço sua intenção de contribuir com o site! Espero que continue tendo sucesso em obter ajuda aqui, e bom aprendizado!

Comment: Acho pertinente a pergunta, fico sempre em duvida nestas coisas na fila de análise - Aliás, acho melhor e recomendo abrir a postagem original pra entender o contexto, em vez de usar a UI de análise. Perde-se uns pontinhos e medalhas, mas é muito melhor para tomar a decisão certa - Eu acho interessante um comentário amistoso antes da remoção, explicando que pretende remover e transformar em comentário, pois apesar da boa intenção, o campo é apenas para respostas ao que foi perguntado inicialmente (e aí apontar pra documentação, e se for novato, reforçar o bem-vindo), e dar um tempo pro OP ver.

Comment: "Perde-se uns pontinhos e medalhas" Faça como eu: abra a postagem original *em uma nova aba*, analise/comente/faça o que achar melhor, e quando tiver certeza da ação correta a ser tomada volte para a aba original e faça lá. ;)

Answer (score 13):

Boa reflexão esta que pode melhorar a receção para usuários novos.

Uma vez que a resposta caso apagada pode ser lida pelo seu autor eu sugiro comentar -> apagar -> inserir como comentário o agradecimento

Duas questões ficam em falta:

- o texto a comentar pelo mod/comunidade
- onde deixar o comentário de agradecimento em nome do usuário (na melhor resposta? na pergunta? em todas as respostas iguais/parecidas à solução que o AP adotou?)

Minha sugestão:

Texto:

> Bom saber que a comunidade ajudou a resolver o seu problema! Em vez de adicionar uma nova resposta para agradecer, vote a favor das respostas que você achar úteis e marque como aceite aquela que melhor respondeu e explicou o problema e sua resposta.

Comentário em nome do AP:

Isto só pode ser feito por um mod e aí tem de ser um mod a decidir o que é melhor.

No caso de ser bem claro quem deu a "melhor resposta" e que o AP adotou então o comentário de agradecimento deverá ir para essa resposta.

No caso de haver multiplas respostas com a mesma solução, não sendo claro quem mais contribuiu para a solução, **ou** o AP usou partes de muitas respostas diferentes, então o comentário deveria ser adicionado na pergunta.

Resta-me uma dúvida: Se um mod comentar uma resposta e depois a deletar o usuário recebe uma notificação quando voltar ao site, para ir lêr esse comment, certo?

Comment: Se deixo um comentário e depois apago a postagem, não tenho certeza, mas acho que a notificação do comentário some. Mas se apago a postagem e deixo um comentário dentro de 1 hora, o usuário é notificado.

Comment: Não era melhor deixar sempre o comentário na pergunta?

Comment: O texto sugerido pro comentário está muito bom. Acho que eu só incluiria uma parte extra pra explicar também *o que* foi feito pelo moderador. Algo como: "Apaguei sua resposta, mas movi o seu agradecimento para o post que te ajudou. Assim o autor fica sabendo que conseguiu te ajudar".

Comment: @Gabe boa ideia. Acho que nessa fase inicial toda a explicação é bemvinda. Juntar esse pedaço é util.

Answer (score 7):

Nesse caso, acho que o melhor caminho é deletar mesmo, mas com um comentário menos enlatado. Algo como "Respostas no SO não são mostradas em ordem cronológica e por isso devem ser auto-contidas. Essa resposta só faz sentido como uma continuação da resposta do Rafael e portanto deve ser removida"

Acredito que o que está confundindo mais nesse caso é que o comentário enlatado que você mencionou não é apropriado para a a resposta do AP. Esse comentário é para pessoas acostumadas com fóruns tradicionais que respondem a pedidos de clarificação da pergunta com um novo post ao invés de uma edição. Outro fator que confunde é que normalmente quando o AP cria uma resposta pra própria pergunta ele fazer alguma modificação a mais, o que justifica a resposta separada (ou talvez uma edição na resposta já dada). Já esse caso é diferente porque o AP não adicionou nada de novo - a única coisa que dá pra fazer é deletar a resposta mesmo.

Comment: Eu não tenho dúvidas que ela deva ser removida, e talvez o comentário enlatado mais adequado seja *Não adicione "obrigado" como resposta. Em vez disso, vote a favor das respostas que você achar úteis.* Eu estou preocupado é com a forma de se fazer isso. Acho que minha preocupação tem a ver com os superpoderes de moderador – para nós o caminho mais curto é simplesmente clicar em "remover", e a resposta some silenciosamente...

Comment: Acho que um comentário mais individualizado é apropriado nessa resposta que estamos discutindo. O AP fez algo um pouco mais complexo do que um simples obrigado e ele já votou/aceitou a resposta que ele achou útil. O problema de verdade é que a resposta dele tá num meio termo em que ela é grande demais pra ser um comentário ou edição e incompleta demais pra ser uma resposta separada.

Comment: É, se for pra converter em comentário só sobra o agradecimento.

Comment: Um caso bem parecido desta semana, e que também me deixou na dúvida: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/54865. Acabei convertendo em comentário, que consistia no "obrigado" e mais uma pequena observação. O código redundante eu cortei.

Comment: @bfavaretto Acho que o que você fez nesse caso foi bem correto. Não vai ser possível fazer a mesma coisa com *todos*  os casos, mas conventer em comentário deixando apenas o conteúdo relevante faz muito sentido.