# Edições apenas para remover saudações/agradecimentos?

Tags: suporte, edição

Li [essa pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/846/sauda%C3%A7%C3%B5es-e-agradecimentos/848#848) e concordei com as respostas, e agora pouco me vi com [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/60121/23262). É cabível editá-la apenas para remover o agradecimento no final? Tenho essa dúvida para qualquer tipo de pergunta também, não apenas essa caso isolado.

Obs.: As tags que coloquei para essa pergunta estão corretas?

Comment: Levando em conta que o SOpt é um site do tipo Q&A, não é legal manter saudações/agradecimentos. Seu 'bom dia' pode não ser válido quando alguém for responder.

Comment: Resposta interessante: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/52/227

Comment: Fechei como duplicata porque penso que qualquer discussão aqui seria uma repetição das respostas da outra questão. Em resumo: "bom dia" ou "obrigado" não machuca ninguém, mas se estiver com disposição edite e remova as saudações porque é uma convenção do site e evita "ruído" para os demais usuários. Isso inclui também trechos inúteis como "estou com um grande problema, pessoal". Se houver outra dúvida mais específica pode postar outra pergunra. Abraço!

Comment: Retirei o texto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/60121/revisions Sinta-se a vontade para fazer isso nas próximas ocasiões. Atente-se pois geralmente existe algo mais a ser melhorando, então se já está com a mão na massa dá uma revisada no texto inteiro, se possível.