# Cancelar uma edição

Tags: novo-recurso, edição, edições-sugeridas

No momento em que eu estava fazendo uma edição, outra pessoa também editou. Quando olhei minhas atividades recentes apareceu que eu editei só o que a pessoa não tinha editado ainda, sendo que as alterações necessárias já haviam sido feitas.

No meu caso foi essa pergunta: [Contar números 1 em número binário após conversão de base decimal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152377/contar-n%c3%bameros-1-em-n%c3%bamero-bin%c3%a1rio-ap%c3%b3s-convers%c3%a3o-de-base-decimal)

Tem como eu cancelar uma sugestão de edição? Pois nesse caso a minha edição ficou inútil, constando apenas algumas coisas irrelevantes para a pergunta.
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/80048

Comment: Sua edição foi rejeitada quando o outro usuário editou e salvou ela.

Comment: Que eu saiba, não, só se for rejeitada.

Comment: Quando eu olhei o review, vi que não fazia sentido nenhum a minha edição depois que já tinha sido feita uma outra edição. Se tivesse um jeito de cancelar a edição, faria os usuário não perderem tempo ao analisar.

Comment: Adicionei algumas dicas a resposta

Comment: E eu adicionei mais algumas "dicas" em comentário na resposta. Muita gente se esquece ou não sabe dessas coisas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A sua edição já está cancelada.

Se uma edição é feita e sobrepõe a sua, então a sua já é **cancelada automaticamente** e é exibido *Rejeitar e Editar*, tal como na imagem:

[image: Rejeitar e Editar]

Isto quer dizer que a sua já foi cancelada automaticamente, mas fica no histórico a sua tentativa de edição, pois o histórico pertence a pergunta, nele vai conter as atividades, edições, etc, ele não influencia em nada para ti, mas é bom para saber o que ocorreu na pergunta e até avaliar comportamentos dos usuários.

### Dicas

Antes de tudo, no meta tem muitas dicas de como usar melhor o site, principalmente na tag [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) (é só clicar nela).

Também pode pesquisar assim:

- https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=formatar+-%5Bbug%5D
- https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=editar+-%5Bbug%5D

Agora algumas dicas para edição

- Não faça edições que mudem o sentido do que foi dito, o que você entende nem sempre pode ser o que o autor quis dizer, a não ser que você tenha muita certeza
- Você pode até mudar uma frase completamente, mas ela tem que transmitir o mesmo sentido do original, desde que torne mais claro que o texto anterior
- Tenha em mente que uma edição deve melhorar e organizar de modo a ajudar quem irá ler a pergunta, fazer pequenas muitas vezes é supérfluo
- Em textos se limite a:

  1. Corrigir pontuação e acentuação
  2. Organizar parágrafos, listas e "quotes"
  3. Se for para editar e corrigir um acento apenas recomendo que faça uma analise de tudo, pois as vezes podem ter mais coisas a serem melhoradas, não faça uma por vez na mesma postagem
- Em códigos:

  1. Nunca mecha no código, como corrigir [indentação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o) ou espaçamentos (isso porque as vezes o problema do código esta nisto)
  2. A única coisa que recomendo mexer no código é quando está sem marcação

Faço das palavras do bigown as minhas:

A ferramenta editar não é para ganhar pontos, isso é apenas uma gratificação pela sua colaboração, a ferramenta deve ser usada para melhorar a postagem.

Outras dicas importantes para ler antes de editar publicações de outras pessoas (sugerido pelo bigown):

- [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/3635)
- [Saudações e Agradecimentos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/846/3635)

Comment: Aos que forem editar: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/101. O é ideal retirar saudações, agradecimentos e outros textos que não servem para nada (Ex.: "estou com uma dúvida", "alguém me ajuda?", "Espero ter ajudado!", ou qualquer coisa que seja uma obviedade). Em um Q&A o conteúdo da pergunta ou resposta deve brilhar, só o que é importante deve ser escrito, como se fosse em uma prova da escola (tudo deve estar bem escrito, claro, objetivo). Isso ajuda passar a ideia de que não é o um fórum: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/846/101. Tb: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/297/101

Comment: @bigown excelente

Comment: Obrigada pelas dicas!!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento na verdade os textos podem ser mudados para qualquer problema ortográfico, gramático e mesmo de clareza. Pode até reescrever todo o texto se for deixar mais claro. Claro que quanto mais radical, mais cuidado deve ter, mais tem que ter certeza que está fazendo o certo, em for muito radical é de bom tom avisar o AP e indicar que ele pode reverter se não gostar, mas alterações substanciais que não mudem o sentido, que não prejudiquem a postagem e que ajudem salvar a pergunta, desde que não altere a intenção do autor, sempre é bom.  Nem todo mundo sabe fazer isso bem em tudo.

Comment: @bigown coloquei como dicas porque é uma recomendação, veja que eu penso assim, muita coisa vai da experiencia, é melhor ser mais limitado no começo e conforme pegar confiança com o site passar a editar, todavia vou editar as dicas

Comment: Uma coisa bem observada é que não é obrigatório resolver todos os problemas das postagens, mas há quem abuse disso, tem quem fica mudando algumas poucas coisas para ganhar 2 pontos e partir para outra rapidinho, em algumas caos ela volta editar a mesma postagem para ganhar mais 2 pontos. O objetivo do recursos é melhor as postagens, não ganhar os pontos, isso é só uma consequência. Eu e muitos usuários rejeitam quando a pessoa não está seguindo as recomendações e aparenta estar só procurando pontos. Quem não sabe fazer deve ser mais limitado mesmo.