# Inibir o uso de saudações

Tags: debate, novo-recurso

Nós já tivemos uma discussão sobre [saudações e agradecimentos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/846/sauda%C3%A7%C3%B5es-e-agradecimentos) no Stack Overflow PT. Pelo que entendi o consenso é de que a gente pode e deve seguir o padrão dos demais stacks, não só de programação, e evitar ruído nos posts. Todos os motivos pelos quais desejar um "bom dia" é desnecessário e, especialmente para um site como este, desagradável, já foram listados lá.

Porém neste momento temos [mil cento e vinte e duas postagens com "bom dia"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22bom+dia%22). Nós temos uma média de algumas por dia na verdade.

Quando a gente escreve perguntas com certas palavras de gatilho, o sistema do SO as vezes dá um aviso - não ocorre aqui no SO em PT, mas a título de exemplo, se você tentar criar uma pergunta no SO original com "help" ou "urgent" no título, você vê um popup que chama bastante atenção:

[image: Um aviso nada discreto de que há algo errado na pergunta]

Tem até link explicando o motivo do aviso.

Seria possível fazer algo semelhante para quando houver alguma saudação no início de um post? Eu digo no início para não pegar casos nos quais a saudação faça parte legítima de um exemplo, i.e.: não bloquear coisas como:

```
// Isto é um exemplo de código
if (DateTime.Now.Hour < 12) return "bom dia sol, bom dia natureza!";
else if (DateTime.Now.Hour < 18) return "boa tarde, jovem!";
else return "boa noite";
```

Acredito que isso ajudaria a manter as postagens mais focadas em problemas e soluções. Independente de ser possível ou não, eu pretendo fazer minha parte e tirar um tempo para remover saudações de posts vez em quando.

<sub>P.s.: eu ainda vou criar uma extensão pra Chrome que substitua "Bom dia" em início de post por "Olá, eu sou lesado"</sub>.

Comment: Mais que pertinente.

Comment: Completamente de acordo com a ideia do aviso.

Comment: No tópico que você cita, de acordo com o Gabe, esse script já está em ação. Será que não é algum outro problema? https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/848/2652