# Qualquer um pode analisar as edições?

Tags: debate, edição

Quantas pessoas são necessárias atualmente para analisar uma edição e aprová-la?
E outra pergunta, o próprio usuário pode automaticamente aprovar ou rejeitar uma edição em sua pergunta(foi tirado os pontos mínimos para análise?)?

Minha pergunta é especificamente para saber se os usuários podem analisar inclusive as edições propostas nas perguntas deles. Ex: Eu edito uma resposta do Usuário X e o próprio Usuário X aprova/rejeita a edição.

Pra mim isso é errado porque se A edita B é porque A acredita que B está errado, e pode melhorar e B 99% das vezes B não vai dar o braço a torcer de que está perguntando de maneira errada. Então, a partir do momento que B analisa e  aprova a edição feita contra uma pergunta do próprio B, anula-se o propósito de uma edição.

Porque hoje estava fazendo algumas edições, e a análise em uma das [perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/111225) foi negada, então resolvi ver qual o motivo, e o AP tinha negado.

Sempre foi assim mesmo e eu nunca percebi ou ocorreu alguma mudança?
<sub>**Não foi um rollback.**</sub>

Além disso, eu fiz errado em remover as saudações e agradecimentos das perguntas, assim como as tags do título?

[image: Print]

Comment: Se o editor for o autor do post, ele aprova sozinho, afinal, ele é o **autor**, ele sabe(ou deveria saber) o que prejudica ou melhora a postagem dele.

Comment: A edição era totalmente aceitável, foi realmente foi exagero da parte do Gabriel, todavia vou deixar algo bem claro que sempre "bato o pé" aqui, se for pra editar tente editar tudo o que é possível, na pergunta tinha ao menos 3 lugares que você poderia ter aplicado o markdown. No caso foi o AP que rejeitou porque ele provavelmente não entende que saudações e coisas como Ajuda, por favor, help-me, etc são redundâncias desnecessárias.

Comment: Seria o BindValue e o Execute()?, se for, agora eu vi isso @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: @SauldaSilva sim exato (detalhe o Gabriel é o dono da pergunta e ele mesmo pode rejeitar, mas outros usuários que participam da fila de analise também pode atuar na média de 5 votos, sendo 3 necessários para aceitar ou rejeitar), sobre as saudações me parece que a maior parte da comunidade concorda tem a mesma concordância, é desnecessário https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/846/3635

Comment: Outro exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/111226

Comment: Realmente @YourCatVini, na verdade eu até achei que fosse duplicata, porque é o mesmo autor e perguntas e os mesmos erros

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Geralmente precisa de duas pessoas para aprovar. Será apenas uma se ela escolher editar adicional ou se quem aprova é um moderador ou o autor original do *post*. Não tenho certeza mas parece que pode exigir mais de dois aprovadores em alguns casos se houver rejeições.

Só pode aprovar quem tem pelo menos 2000 pontos (atualmente). Nessa pontuação não é necessário mas ser aprovado.

Não é para editar erros é para editar imperfeições. Se algo está errado faça o certo você. Pode ser intenção do autor fazer daquele jeito.

Se a pessoa rejeitar uma mudança azar o dela. Se for muito importante pode sinalizar para chamar atenção dos moderadores ou discutir no meta ou no chat.

Sua edição estava correta. Quer fazer de novo? Esperamos que seja aprovada agora. Caso contrário, sinalize.