# Por que uma edição necessita ser aprovada por duas pessoas?

Tags: debate, edição, edições-sugeridas

A partir da pontuação 2.000, você já pode editar publicações sem a necessidade de ir para a fila de análise para alguém aprovar ou não. O sistema confia que você sabe o que está fazendo e então a edição é aprovada imediatamente, em qualquer publicação.

A dúvida é que, quando um usuário que não tem dois mil pontos ainda, edita algo, vai para a análise. A análise é feita por quem já tem mais de dois mil pontos. Por que duas pessoas precisam aprovar àquela edição e não somente uma?

Não vejo coerência onde alguém que edita tem imediato efeito e ainda assim precisa de uma segunda aprovação numa edição de terceiro. Ambos quem aprovam, podem editar imediatamente quando solos, mas não quando é de outra pessoa.

> Geralmente precisa de duas pessoas para aprovar. Será apenas uma se ela escolher editar adicional ou se quem aprova é um moderador ou o autor original do post.
>
> *<sup>- Maniero na resposta aceita de [Qualquer um pode analisar as edições?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6013/qualquer-um-pode-analisar-as-edi%C3%A7%C3%B5es)</sup>*

A edição original por terceiro precisa de aprovação de dois usuários. Mas se um usuário complementar a edição feita pelo editor, ela é imediatamente aprovada. Qual a lógica disso?

Gostaria de entender o porquê disso e qual o sentido deste também.

Comment: Atualmente eu estou achando pouco ter duas, dada a quantidade de edits supérfluos ou mesmo errados sendo aprovados que tenho visto, em especial nos últimos dias. O edit não me assusta tanto, a aprovação é o pior. Eu poria uns 5 no mínimo para a situação que estamos vivendo, e a aprovação do próprio AP valeria como 3 votos desses 5 (ainda precisaria de mais 2).

Comment: Um usuário pode se enganar ao fazer a avaliação, eu essa semana me enganei. Tem usuário que aprova tudo indiscriminadamente. Tem usuário pedante que se mete a analisar conteúdo que desconhece. São N os motivos para esse modelo de aprovação.

Comment: Como curiosidade, antigamente só precisava de um pra aprovar. [Depois mudaram pra 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151536/401803), com o objetivo de diminuir as aprovações de edições ruins.

Comment: @AugustoVasques o que impede de uma edição SUA for um engano? Se você fazer uma edição por engano em terceiros, não vejo problema em reverter. O importante é reconhecer o engano.

Comment: @CypherPotato se eu me enganar em uma edição eu posso a corrigir quando perceber o erro. Um erro de aprovação não pode ser desfeito a não ser que seja feita uma nova edição. E um erro de rejeição submete a perda de todo o conteúdo editado.

Comment: CypherPotato eu concordo contigo. Acho que a ideia do @Bacco se entende, mas não tem muita lógica, visto que qualquer um pode melhorar ou rejeitar e editar e fica na hora.

Comment: @JorgeB. mais do que lógica, é fato. Basta acompanhar a fila de edição e vai ver aprovações constantes que não deveriam ter sido feitas. A idéia da fila é fazer uma triagem (se não precissasse de triagem não teria fila) - mas pra isso precisa realmente que seja feita corretamente. De tempos em tempos sempre tem uns dois ou três que saem (não sei se por medalha ou o que) passando na fila aparentemente sem sequer ler (dada a velocidade entre ações). Acho mais improvável que cinco de uma vez façam isso (lembrando que os mods podem acelerar o processo, mas não "segurar" ele).

Comment: @Bacco é um bom ponto de vista. Embora eu ache que isso é apenas uma rolha, o real problema continua, o mau uso da ferramente. Mas pode ser que dê certo.

Comment: @JorgeB. só achei por bem comentar, pois como mod aqui é um problema que eu tenho esbarrado diariamente (sei que você tem experiência como mod, mas o pt.se é bem mais organizado nesse sentido, e tem um público aparentemente mais comprometido atualmente).

Comment: @JorgeB. Se alguém não presta atenção numa edição, certamente não presta atenção nas demais filas de análise. Embora algumas filas de análise exigem 5 pessoas para aprovação, a edição acaba sendo a mais sem sentido, mas não pela exigência de duas pessoas, mas de que uma sozinha consegue imediata aprovação mas em terceiro não.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EU acho que deveria ser mais porque muita aprovação é ruim (tem casos que o AP aprova sozinho, ele pode fazer isto, e é uma edição ruim). Acho que até deveria ter um critério mais rígido de quem pode aprovar.

O motivo é justamente pra ter mais de uma opinião se a edição está correta e evitar aprovações de edições ruins facilmente. É como o fechamento que exige 5 pessoas, para ter certeza que aquilo é o correto.

Se a pessoa se dá ai trabalho de editar provavelmente ela está se comprometendo mais com a questão e deve fazer algo certo. Um dos grandes problemas das listas é as pessoas votarem sem nem olhar só pra ganhar medalha, esta é uma forma de reduzir os erros por causa disto. Não é perfeito mas ajuda inibir mau uso.

O motivo exato de ser duas e não três ou cinco é mais difícil de estabelecer, provavelmente porque não queriam dificultar muito aprovar edição que é muito importante, inclusive porque edições deve ter mais que fechamentos (ou deveria ser, no passado era assim, hoje já não sei, "todo mundo" cansou de editar e tem tanta coisa ruim para fechar).

Comment: +1 ... Exemplos: outro dia foi ao contrário, um usuario apesar de iniciante notou que que havia copiado um código duas vezes e mudei parte e esqueci a outra, na mesma resposta uma parte era sobre exceptions e outra sobre ifs, e a edição dele foi totalmente pertinente, ai 2 usuários que pelo que conheço não entendem da linguagem que estava na resposta, rejeitaram a edição.

Comment: Exemplo 2: Também teve aprovadas em perguntas aonde o erro de sintaxe era causado ou pela tabulação (python) ou quebra de linha (em uma sintaxe especifica), ai alguém editou ajustando a tabulação e na outra a quebra de linha, o que corrigia o erro. Tive que reverter, a sorte foi que notei. Não vou postar os links aqui, mas alguns eu salvei para acaso precisasse "sinalizar" repetidas situações.

Comment: Sim, acontece muito, Devemos aumentar os votos pra aprovar edição para 3 :D