# Edição de publicações

Tags: debate, edições-sugeridas

Hoje realizei uma correção visual em uma publicação que ao meu ver ficou de acordo com que é esperado.

Demarquei todos os pontos que contém referencia a **métodos ou funções** me utilizando do **{}** e removi palavras desnecessárias para a explicação de um problema.

Porém, depois notei que foi rejeitada com o argumento:

> Esta edição não corrigiu problemas críticos na publicação - visualize o histórico de revisão para ver o que deveria ter sido alterado

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/114297

Tudo bem, eu entendi o argumento. E aceitei.

Fui ver então qual era o resultado esperado. Bem, para minha surpresa só foi removido a palavra "Bom dia".

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/210959/revisions

Fiquei meio sem entender uma coisa.

Qual a diferença entre minha edição e a edição aprovada?

Comment: Eu rejeitei porque você monoespaçou tudo. Nada daquilo precisava ser monoespaçado ao meu ver. Eu sempre tento seguir [este post aqui do meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/18246) para guiar as minhas edições e também para revisar as edições da fila. Pra ser bem sincero, eu não sei se no momento a minha intenção não foi "Aceitar e melhorar", porque eu sempre acho importante considerar o trabalho do editor, mesmo que eu só vá aproveitar uma palavra desta edição.

Comment: **Retificando**: Na verdade, tem bastante coisa que deveria ser monoespaçada, com a exceção de uma ou duas palavras do início. Provavelmente eu cliquei no botão errado.

Comment: Alías, seria legal você remover os cumprimentos e agradecimentos nas suas edições e não abusar do _monospace_. De qualquer forma, sua edição está ótima e foi erro meu. Estamos resolvidos?

Comment: Só lembrando que a edição do @linko não uma simples remoção das palavras "bom dia". [Saudações e agradecimentos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/846/28595) é algo que sempre removemos e já foi discutido no meta,com bastante aceitação dos demais.

Comment: Eu teria aceito da forma como estava. De qualquer forma, logo logo você chegará a um nível de reputação no qual não precisará passar pela fila de revisões, então não esquente com isso.

Comment: @LINQ não existe nada a ser resolvido, só vim tirar uma dúvida para eu conseguir melhorar minhas próximas edições. Até por que eu estou aprendendo. Mas tudo bem, eu adicionei aquele seu link aqui nos meus favoritos para eu ter uma base também. Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: @Everson É exatamente o que eu quis dizer. Se ficou claro o que aconteceu.

Comment: @LINQ tranquilo. Acho que esse debate pode ser finalizado pois sanou minhas dúvidas. Obrigado pelo tempo e compreensão.