# Qual é a posição do SOpt em relação à inserção de gírias em posts?

Tags: suporte, perguntas, comportamento

É comum perceber que alguns usuários novatos do Stack Overflow utilizam-se de gírias em seus diálogos. Quer seja em perguntas, quer seja em respostas.

Dentre as gírias que já presenciei, e atualmente me lembro, algumas são até recorrentes, tais como: "e ae", "beleza", "amigão", "brother", etc.

Gostaria de saber o ponto de vista do Stack Overflow em relação às gírias.

Desde já, deixo claro que sou terminantemente contra o uso de gírias em publicações técnicas.

Comment: Basicamente, tudo que não é tecnicamente relevante, seja gíria ou não, deve ser removido: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/846/112052

Comment: Eu não sou absolutamente contra o uso aqui e ali quando é muito pertinente para contar a estórias necessárias. E não acho que estamos falando de *papers* que precisam ser muito formais. Mas em geral elas são desnecessárias e é considerada ruído em quase todas situações. Além disso mostra pouco profissionalismo e e em última análise em **alguns casos**, desrespeito aos demais, o que pode atrair um visão negativa à postagem. È aquela coisa, a pessoa pode postar o que quiser, o que não garante que não haverá consequências. Em outros tempos eu removia tudo isso, hoje raramente o faço porque não...

Comment: consigo mais mexer em tudo, mexo quase que só no que respondo, e eu raramente respondo perguntas postadas dessa forma, não porque tinha gíria, mas quase sempre que tem é de alguém que não consegue postar algo coerente. A gíria costuma ser uma expressão de limitação de vocabulário o que faz a pessoa ter outras limitações até para produzir uma boa pergunta.